# Grails 2.0 Hibernate Annotation - Not working

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-annotations, grails-2.0

I created simple grails with hibernate annotation sample as given in documentation.

I am using scaffolding.

The exception when I click the new Book is as follows

```
No such property: action for class: com.books.Book. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: action for class: com.books.Book
   Line | Method
->>  19 | create  in com.books.BookController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . in     ''
^   662 | run     in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Please post more of your code (like, the Book class and the BookController if it isn't generated at run-time)

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported as a bug - http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8641 - and will be fixed in 2.0.1.

Comment: Thanks, Wasted couple of hours over this. This sucks.

Comment: You can get a full refund for your Grails purchase price at any time ;)